# Select quantity of record instances separated by weeks

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the below:

```
CompanyID |  Logged      | UniqueID
A         |  2014-06-24  | 8
B         |  2014-06-24  | 7
A         |  2014-06-16  | 6
B         |  2014-06-16  | 5
A         |  2014-06-08  | 4
B         |  2014-06-08  | 3
A         |  2014-06-01  | 2
B         |  2014-06-01  | 1
```

I'm stuck trying to create an SQL statement that will return the quantity of rows found for each unique CompanyID, separated into 4 week periods, so something like the below:

```
CompanyID | Period (week)  | Quantity
A         | 0              | 1
B         | 0              | 1
A         | 1              | 1
B         | 1              | 1
A         | 2              | 1
B         | 2              | 1
A         | 3              | 1
B         | 3              | 1
```

I have done something similar before, except by the last 7 days instead of last 4 weeks, but am not sure if this can be reworked:

```
select CompanyID, 
case DATE_FORMAT(Logged, '%Y%m%d') 
when '20140618' then '0' 
when '20140619' then '1' 
when '20140620' then '2' 
when '20140621' then '3' 
when '20140622' then '4' 
when '20140623' then '5' 
when '20140624' then '6' 
end as period , 
count(UniqueID) as quantity from TABLE
where DATE_FORMAT(Logged, '%Y%m%d') 
in (20140618,20140619,20140620,20140621,20140622,20140623,20140624) group by CompanyID, 
DATE_FORMAT(Logged, '%Y%m%d')
```

Is there a more straightforward way to obtain the output desired above?

Comment: Do the periods start from the time of the query and extend back from that point, or are they calendar weeks?

Comment: The periods are calendar weeks

Comment: have you looked at using user-defined variables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?
[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62b56/4) to test with

Theres the original query that doesn't use any hard coding... that is generally a really bad practice. it will have the count inflated by 1 since it starts with one and you want it to start with zero so to fix this do a `select` of the original query where you fix the count and then also not show the user defined variable

```
SELECT CompanyID, Period - 1 as Period, Quantity FROM(
SELECT 
  CompanyID,
  if(@a = Logged, @b, @b := @b + 1) as Period,
  COUNT(*) as Quantity,
  @a := Logged
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT @a := '', @b := 0) as temp
GROUP BY UniqueID
ORDER BY Period
) as subQuery
```

---

ORIGINAL QUERY

```
SELECT 
  CompanyID,
  if(@a = Logged, @b, @b := @b + 1) as Period,
  COUNT(*) as Quantity,
  @a := Logged
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT @a := '', @b := 0) as temp
GROUP BY UniqueID
ORDER BY Period
```